# Import Paypal "bank statement" in Odoo 10 community

Tags: odoo

Bank Statement import format files are features of Odoo 10 Enterprise.
Is there any alternative or CSV format file allowed in Odoo 10 community to import bank statements?

Specifically,

1) is there any open source module to import commonly accepted bank statement formats?
2) is there anything to import PayPal CSV format?

Comment: Just take a look at [OCA bank-statement-import repository](https://github.com/OCA/bank-statement-import) :-)

Comment: I have installed account_bank_statement_import_ofx (OFX is fine as you can convert from csv to OFX), but I get "Register type <! is not valid". (I have tried with severla OFX files and it seems it does not parse OFX, required python ofx parsing lib is installed.